# Redefinition of Assignment Operator

Tags: c, operators, c-preprocessor, operator-keyword

It is in my understanding that several languages use `:=` as the assignment operator. This is implemented to possibly avoid any confusion with the `==` operator. This seemed like a very valid point to me, so I was thinking of how to implement it in a language like **C**. Here is what I was thinking.

```
#define := =
// ... later on

int x := 4;
```

Although this would work (if the preprocessor supported that syntax), it would still allow me to get away with using the `=` operator. So my question is, **Is there a way to "flag" a symbol or operator / Is there a way to prevent the use of some defined operator or symbol?** Again, here is what I was thinking, but I don't know about the syntactical / semantical legality of this.

```
#undef =
```

Comment: Don't. Just don't....

Comment: Operators are not identifiers in C, they are reserved words.  This should never work, thank god.  The least you would have to do to get this working is write your own preprocessor.

Comment: You are correct.  Even very experienced C coders are known to fall into the =/== problem.  I agree with @MitchWheat that doing what you propose is not a good idea; mostly because it makes it very difficult for the next guy to try to maintain the code.  Instead, I take a different approach.  For example, when I compare with a constant, I -always- place the constant first.  ie: if(4 == x)... rather than if(x == 4).  If, by mistake, I write if(4 = x), the compiler will complain.

Comment: Incidentally, compilers will generally complain about the statement if(x=4); due to it being such a common mistake [ to eliminate the compiler complaint, you must write it as: if((x=4)) ].

Comment: @MahonriMoriancumer: You typoed your last comment. `if (x = 4)` is a common mistake; the corrected version is `if (x == 4)`.

Comment: @MahonriMoriancumer: So-called ["Yoda conditions"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions) like `if (4 == x)` are one way to avoid typos -- but I personally find them jarring and counterintuitive.

Comment: Brian: Did your compiler really accept that macro definition? What compiler are you using?

Comment: @keith the macro was purely hypothetical. I was wondering if there was a way to simulate something like that.

Comment: It wasn't at all clear from your question that the example was meant to be hypothetical. I've edited your question to make that clearer. Feel free to re-edit if I've misunderstood.

Comment: [If you want X you know where to find it](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/I/If-you-want-X--you-know-where-to-find-it-.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#define := =
```

A macro name can only be an identifier. I'd be quite surprised if any C compiler accepted that definition. In principle, a compiler could accept it as a language extension, but gcc, for example, does not. Any conforming C compiler must at least issue a diagnostic.

You say it works; I'm frankly skeptical. What compiler are you using?

```
#undef =
```

Same problem.

I can see (and even agree with) your point that using `:=` rather than `=` for the assignment operator would have been a better idea. But using the preprocessor to alter the language like this, even in cases where it works, is rarely a good idea.

C programmers know that `=` means assignment. Anyone reading your code can probably guess that `:=` is *meant* to be assignment, but it would just make your code that much harder to read.

Answer (score 1):

Standard C does not allow the '=' assignment operator to be undefined, or changed.  However, the source code to several C compilers is available; and you are welcome to make your own modifications to your build of a C compiler.  Including changing '=' to ':='.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Good question, but don't do that. Your method results in bad readability.